# Why is my localhost not loading for node.js?

Tags: node.js

So what I am doing is learning node.js and what I'm not able to do is find out why my localhost is not loading at all.

I have tried changing the port number etc etc. but my internet connection is working just fine so that is not the problem, one thing it does is that it loads and then it just continues to do so until it says "Localhost didn't send any data".

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');


const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.rul === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('<h1>Home</h1>');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I expect for the local host to load and display, "Home" at the top of the page. The server was working a little bit ago but not anymore.

Comment: is `req.rul` a typo or in fact a part of your code?

Comment: I think you want `req.url`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Sorry added the answer before I read this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using req.url not req.rul. req.rul should return you undefined and that means it never goes inside your loop.

Just print out the values if you are having trouble understanding why the conditions are not working